# Ambiguity in default constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, default-constructor

I'm trying to understand some of the default options for constructors introduced in C++11, so I was reading some [notes from Bjarne](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#default).

On this page, he was the following example:

```
struct Z {
    // ...

    Z(long long);     // can initialize with an long long
    Z(long) = delete; // but not anything less
};
```

He notes that `Z` can be constructed with a `long long`, but *not anything less*. This phrasing is a little unclear to me. I assumed "anything less" might refer to anything that occupies less space than a `long long`.

I tested some sizes on my machine and found that `long long` requires 8 bytes and a `long double` requires 16 bytes, so I assumed that constructing with a `long double` would be fine, and would simply truncate the fractional part and coerce it to a `long long`.

I wrote this:

```
class Foo {
  public:
    Foo(long long x) : x(x) {}
    Foo(long x) = delete;
  private:
    long long x;
};

int main() {
  Foo foo1(100LL); // Compiles fine
  // Foo foo2(100L); // Compile error - cannot construct with smaller than `long long`. This is obvious
  Foo foo3(42.0L); // This causes an error

  return 0;
}
```

To my surprise, the above code resulted in an error:

> error: call of overloaded 'Foo(long double)' is ambiguous
>      Foo foo3(42.0L);

This seems unambiguous to me. Why can the compiler not resolve this?

Comment: I think He's referring to promotions and not narrowing conversions.

Comment: "Anything less" here means "anything that could be promoted to `long` via standard promotions"

Comment: @IgorTandetnik "Promotion" is the wrong term here, since e.g. `short`is never "promoted" to `long`, but  just converted.

Comment: I believe conversions from `double` to either `long` or `long long` have equal rank for overload resolution purposes, hence the ambiguity.

Comment: @Columbo OK, entering pedantic mode: "anything less" here means "anything for which an implicit conversion sequence to `long` has the same or better rank (**[over.ics.scs]**) than an implicit conversion sequence to `long long`."

Comment: @erip you seem to be committing the fallacy of "denying the antecedent": the claim "Z can be constructed with a long long, but not anything less" is true, but it does not imply "Z must be constructable from other things that are not long long and not less than long long".  The case of `long double` is not addressed by BS's statement

Comment: @M.M Maybe you missed the part where I addressed this: `This phrasing is a little unclear to me. I assumed "anything less" might refer to anything that occupies less space than a long long.` I didn't understand what "anything less" meant, so I made a guess.

Comment: @erip I seemed to me that you were guessing that "anything less" did NOT include `long double`.   (Otherwise your example confirms BS's statement). You even said explicitly "I assumed that constructing with a long double would be fine"  . What is your basis for that assumption, if not a misreading of BS's statement to say "anything not less than long long would be fine"?

Comment: @M.M That's correct, I guessed that "anything less" didn't include `long double` - also addressed by my testing, concluding that `sizeof(long long)` is `8` and `sizeof(long double)` is `16`.

Comment: @M.M I think my question explains everything clearly: His wording was vague. I made an assumption about what it meant. My assumption was wrong. I wanted to understand why my assumption was wrong. If your point was to point out my logical fallacy, good job. If it was to be helpful, you haven't done a good job.

Comment: @erip I think your assumption was correct , but I was saying that BS did not claim that greater types would work.  He only claimed that lesser types would not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A deleted constructor is *declared*, but not defined. Instead of *undefined*, it is *deleted*.

And when the compiler does function overload resolution, it will use the collection of declared compatible functions, that includes deleted functions too. If the overload resolution happens to select a deleted function, then you'll get a compiler error. And if the overload resolution cannot decide the best function, you'll also get a compiler error, even if the ambiguity comes from deleted functions.

You might think that it would be better that deleted functions do not take part in overload resolution. But that would be quite less useful. If you don't want `Foo(long)` to participate in overload resolution, just do not write it!

This is similar to overload with public/private functions. Even when calling from outside the class, public and private functions participate in overload resolution:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    void fun(long long);
private:
    void fun(long);
};
int main()
{
    Foo f;
    f.fun(100LL); //ok
    f.fun(100L); //error: fun(long) is private
    f.fun(1.0); //error: call is ambiguous
}
```

Comment: "Happens to" gives me a little heartburn. This suggests that the compiler *may* choose a delete function, but won't always.

Comment: @erip: Well, overload resolution is well defined, but all the exact rules are hard to remember. Most of the time, they just work and select the proper function. Here _proper_ means _the one I'd choose_.

Comment: What about `f.fun(100);` ?

Comment: @M.M: That is an ambiguous call. Converting an integer to either `long` or `long long` counts as a non-trivial convesion, and so both are equally good candidates.